# Dual boot Win 7 Ubuntu - home and boot partitions have no mount point

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

After installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 on a Windows 7 laptop, running Ubuntu Disk Utility showed the following partition information;

```
/dev/sda1 NTFS, Bootable, Filesystem, Labled: System Reserved, 105MB, Not Mounted

/dev/sda2 NTFS, no flag, Filesystem, no label, 84GB, Not Mounted

/dev/sda3 Usage: Container for logical partitions. Partition Type: Extended (0x05). no flags. no label. Capacity: 416GB

/dev/sda5 Usage: Filesystem. Partition Type: Linux (0x83). no partition label. no flags.  Capacity: 999MB. Type: Ext4(ver 1.0). Available: -. Label: -. Mount Point: Not Mounted

/dev/sda8 Usage: Filesystem. Partition Type: Linux (0x83). no partition label. no flags.  Capacity: 30GB. Type: Ext4(ver 1.0). Available: -. Label: -. Mount Point: Mounted at /

/dev/sda6 Usage: Filesystem. Partition Type: Linux (0x83). no partition label. no flags.  Capacity: 377GB. Type: Ext4(ver 1.0). Available: -. Label: -. Mount Point: Not Mounted

/dev/sda7 Usage: Swap Space. Partition Type: Linux (0x82). no partition label. no flags.  Capacity: 8.4GB.
```

sda2 contains Windows 7 but without a mount point

sda6 should have been the Home partition and sda5 should have been the Boot partition but the mount points seem to have been lost and now everything but Swap has gone into the root partition sda8 (the Home folder also seems to be within sda8).

How do I go about getting sda6 used as the Home partition and sda5 as Boot

Output of /etc/fstab as requested

```
pb@LC1:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information. 
# 
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a 
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices 
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5). 
# 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0  
# / was on /dev/sdb8 during installation 
UUID=f80d2f67-db1e-42a7-a321-437c94354623 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1  
# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation  
UUID=06fcb820-41d6-4767-92a7-99baf6849673 none            swap    sw              0       0  
pb@LC1:~$
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of your `/etc/fstab` file, please?

Comment: Contents as requested   pb@LC1:~$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information. 
# 
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass> 
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0 
# / was on /dev/sdb8 during installation 
UUID=f80d2f67-db1e-42a7-a321-437c94354623 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1 
# swap was on /dev/sdb7 during installation 
UUID=06fcb820-41d6-4767-92a7-99baf6849673 none            swap    sw              0       0 
pb@LC1:~$

Comment: Please add additional information to the question instead of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/fstab` doesn't contain any file system except `/`. Hence nothing else is mounted automatically during boot. You can either

1. reconfigure your system to use the additional volumes (requires (re-)mounting, moving stuff around, editing fstab, and `update-grub`), or
2. format the Linux partitions and reinstall Ubuntu and tell the installer about your custom partition setup (choose the option "something else" when asked).

If you break your installation during 1., you can still go with 2. though.

Comment: Do you think that your option 2 is a better bet than uninstalling Ubuntu, deleting the 4 ext4 partitions and then installing from scratch (but using the "something else" option, I still want a Home partition)

Comment: That's what I actually had in mind when writing option 2. Thanks for making me clarify that.